# u-boot how to mark bad blocks

Tags: u-boot, badblocks, ubifs

While in U-boot in an arm based board (wb45n),
I manually erase and then mark a block bad.

> U-Boot> nand erase 0x00720000 20000
>
> NAND erase: device 0 offset 0x00720000, size 0x20000
>   Erasing at 0x720000 -- 100% complete.
>   OK
>   U-Boot> nand markbad 0x00720000
>   block 0x00720000 successfully marked as bad
>   U-Boot> nand bad
>   >
>   Device 0 bad blocks:
>     00720000

I write software and can see the bad blocks being skipped in the process.

> NAND write: device 0 offset 0x5e0000, size 0x16c0000
>   Skip bad block 0x00720000
>    23855104 bytes written: OK

After the software writing, I reboot and the bad blocks are not there.

> U-Boot> nand bad
>   >
>   Device 0 bad blocks:
>   U-Boot>

Seems as if they have been automatically corrected.
If I don't erase the blocks before marking them bad, I can write software successfully but I (often but not always) get the following error during the kernel boot:
(I don' t really know why this error message is produced, any explanations are welcome)

> UBI error: scan_peb: bad image sequence number 1748114077 in PEB 175, expected 1578922167
>
> Erase counter header dump:
>
> ```
>     magic          0x55424923
>     version        1
>     ec             1
>     vid_hdr_offset 2048
>     data_offset    4096
>     image_seq      1748114077
>     hdr_crc        0x285278f
> ```
>
> Starting kernel ...
>
> Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.
>
> add to erase: PEB 0, EC 0
>   UBI error: ubi_compare_lebs: unsupported on-flash UBI format
>   UBI error: ubi_attach_mtd_dev: failed to attach mtd6, error -22
>   UBI error: ubi_init: cannot attach mtd6
>   UBIFS error (pid 1): ubifs_mount: cannot open "ubi0:rootfs", error -19
>   Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown- block(0,0)

What I am trying to do is test the board to see how many bad blocks it can 
handle before failing.

Is the way I mark the bad blocks correct?
Why do the bad blocks disappear?
Is there a way to mark bad blocks that will persist?
What does the last error mean?

Answer (score 2):

https://community.nxp.com/thread/334536#comment-453692

> the error is related to a problem in the flashing of the board, that
>   is:
>
> 1. you flash a new image incorrectly - you do not erase *whole* flash
> 2. you flash a new image - by erasing only the erase blocks where you write, but not erasing the rest of eraseblock.

I can imagine this happening if

- you omitted your `nand erase` or
- you wrote an image with N blocks marked bad on the NAND, then subsequently wrote the same image but with N-1 blocks marked bad on the NAND.  After the end of the current image, there would be 1 block left over at the end from the previous image, which would not have been overwritten.